# Non-split extension of representations of $\mathrm{GL}_2$ and $\mathrm{Hom}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, langlands-conjectures, p-adic-groups, modular-representation-theory

Let $0\to V_1\to V\to V_1\to0$ be a sequence of representations of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ over $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$, where $V_1$ is irreducible, smooth and admissible. Assume that this sequence is non-split. Then I'd like to know how to prove that $\dim_{\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p}\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)}(V, V_1)=1$.

Is there some direct way to see this? I also want to know if $V_1$ is the unique subrepresentation of $V$, which is equivalent to $\mathrm{soc}(V)=V_1$, where $\mathrm{soc}(V)$ is the maximal semisimple subrepresentation of $V$.

Comment: It's obviously at least one, and if it's more then take another linearly independent one and compose it with the inclusion of $V_1$ and you'll see that the sequence splits. You might also take a look at the long exact sequence of Hom and Ext, and see what the connecting homomorphism is doing.

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate on Dave Benson's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457125/non-split-extension-of-representations-of-mathrmgl-2-and-mathrmhom#comment1183968_457125). Suppose there exists a homomorphism $f\colon V\to V_1$ whose restriction to $V_1$ is non-zero. By Schur's lemma, $f\rvert_{V_1}$ is a non-zero constant, and hence by multiplying $f$ by some element of $\smash{\overline{\mathbb F}}_p^\times$ you may assume $f\rvert_{V_1}$ is the identity. But then $f$ is exactly a splitting of the injection $V_1\hookrightarrow V$, a contradiction.

Comment: non-constant = not a scalar multiple of the identity?

Comment: @LSpice Yes, sorry, I meant non-zero.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457125/non-split-extension-of-representations-of-mathrmgl-2-and-mathrmhom/457134#comment1184028_457134), OK, thanks.  I misread the condition (and so my apologies also to @SimonWadsley for my silly misreading, now deleted, of their [clarification](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457125/non-split-extension-of-representations-of-mathrmgl-2-and-mathrmhom/457134#comment1184019_457134)).